# Datepart MONTH invalid column

Tags: sql, hana, datepart

```
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, SentTime)  
FROM myTable
```

Where SentTime is a timestamp (ex. 2019-04-22 11:16:00)
Its the same deal even if I do a different datepart such as WEEK, wk, year, etc

> SQL Error [260] [HY000]:(at 16): invalid column name: MONTH: line 1
> col 17 (at pos 16)  invalid column name: MONTH: line 1 col 17 (at pos
> 16)

Thank you

Comment: There must be another problem...
What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: seems like it is working fine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/21d69/2. Should be some other issue.

Comment: That doesn't look like a typically formatted error message from Microsoft SQL Server. What type of DBMS are you using?

Comment: Looks like a SAP  DB message instead of SQL Server or MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

`DATEPART` is a MS SQL Server function; with SAP HANA you can use either `MONTH()` or `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM <value>)`.